# Possible solution to initialization order fiasco?

Tags: c++

Reading a lot about this well known problem I discovered and used the "Creation on first use", but it main problem is that it produces memory leaks.

Working a bit, I've done some light modification trying to solve that problem, and I got a solution:

1) Using a global static pointer instead a local static pointer

2) Using a separate function to delete the object.

Example:

```
static myObject* myObjectPtr=nullptr;

static myObjectDel() {delete myObjectPtr;}

inline myObject& myObjectRef()
{
  if(myObjectPtr==nullptr)
  {
    myObjectPtr=new myObjectPtr;
    atexit(myObjectDel);
  }

  return(*myObjectPtr);
}
```

So, I can ensure that:

1) The object is created before first use.

2) The object is deleted after last use.

3) There are no memory leaks.

It works with MS Visual Studio 2013 due the static pointer is zero-initialized at program startup, but I'm not sure if all compilers and operating systems does it.

In other words, Is it portable?

Thanks you and sorry for my poor english (I'm not english native)

Comment: As a sidenote, any modern solution should avoid naked pointers, use shared or unique ptr instead.

Answer (score 5):

Your solution is portable, but it's not thread-safe.
It's also needlessly complicated.

Don't use dynamic allocation:

```
inline myObject& myObjectRef()
{
    static myObject theObject;
    return theObject;
}
```

Leak-free (since the dawn of time) and thread-safe (since C++11).

Comment: I'm tempted to pinch this. This is an excellent idea. Have an upvote.

Comment: However only thread-safe in C++11 and newer (nevertheless the OP solution isn't thread-safe either, so I guess he doesn't have such requirement).

Comment: This is _the_ way to do singletons. And has been for years!

Answer (score 1):

I'd prefer `static myObject* myObjectPtr;` since all `static` pointers will be initialised to `nullptr` anyway. The C++ standard guarantees that.

But your code is vulnerable to two threads calling `inline myObject& myObjectRef()` for the first time which *could* lead to multiple `new` to be balanced with only one `delete`. You ought to use a mutex in that function to obviate that.

Comment: I don't think the use of "zero initialised" is correct, not in C++. A `static` pointer is initialised to the `nullptr` value, even if that doesn't correspond to a zero bit pattern. (That's why you use the `{}` notation for automatic instance of classes with pointer members, rather than a memset(... 0) )

Comment: I only have cppreference to guide me at the moment. But it seems you are indeed correct, and I was wrong. http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/zero_initialization.